# How to open Contact using intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I have been using the following code to open contact in android.
But it  is not  showing  symbol of  **contactID** and  **context**

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, String.valueOf(contactID));
        intent.setData(uri);
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Assuming that `contactID` is the proper value, that code may work. Please edit your question and explain, **in detail**, what problems you are experiencing with this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.. its working for me

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact");
    context.startActivity(intent);
```